CakePHP 5 - How to include the Authentication plugin within a component?
This part of the code works (simplified part):
class UsersController extends AppController
{

public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
}    

public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

     //...

    $protectedMethods = ['login', 'logout', 'edit'];
    if (!empty($this->request->getAttribute('identity')) && 
        in_array($this->request->getAttribute('identity')->get('role'), array_keys(ADMINROLES)) && 
        in_array($this->request->getParam('action'), $protectedMethods)) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        $this->Authentication->logout();
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    }       
}
}

I want to convert the part of the code located within the beforeFilter into a component function, as it is repeated in many other controllers, and simplify the PHP code as follows:
This part of the code DOES NOT work (simplified part):
    class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize(): void
    {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
    $this->loadComponent('AuthenticationBlocker');
}    

public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    ...
    // Blocking access to protected functions for admins
    $this->AuthenticationBlocker->adminRoles(['login', 'logout', 'edit']);     
}
}

The component looks like this:
class AuthenticationBlockerComponent extends Component {

// The other component your component uses
protected array $components = ['Flash', 'Authentication.Authentication'];
public $controller;

public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->controller = $this->getController();
}


public function adminRoles($methods) {
if (!empty($this->getController()->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity')) AND in_array($this->getController()->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity')->get('role'),array_keys(ADMINROLES)) AND in_array($this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('action'),$methods)){
$this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
$this->Authentication->logout();
return $this->controller->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
}
}
    }

The part of the code where the error occurs is: $this->Authentication->logout();

I'm not sure if you can use a component from within another component, or if you can how you make sure it's a properly configured component. I'd probably approach this by extending the Authentication component, then you can use $this in your new function and it will have all the functionality you expect from the Authentication component, because it is in fact the Authentication component. On the other hand, I'm not always the best at structuring code to be elegant...

I don't think it's the right approach. Maybe you should send Authentication.identity as a parameter?

    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class AuthenticationBlockerComponent extends Component {

// The other component your component uses
protected array $components = ['Flash','Authentication.Authentication'];
public $controller;

public function beforeFilter()
{
$this->controller = $this->getController();
}

//Blocking access to administration for admins  
public function adminRoles(array $methods): void {
    $identity = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity');
    $action = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('action');
    // Check if user is logged in and has admin role and if the action is in allowed methods
    if ($identity AND in_array($identity->get('role'), array_keys(ADMINROLES)) AND in_array($action, $methods)) {
        $this->controller->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        $this->controller->Authentication->logout();
        $this->controller->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    }
}

}

